# select value into viarble in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, rowcount

I need some help with a query.

I want to select row count value from a table, and then to use the value in a different query. For example:

```
@rowcount = select count(*) from MyTable

select A*@rowcount, B/@rowcount
from MyOtherTable
```

Can someone show my what is the correct syntax? I need to use `@rowcount` a lot of times so i prefer to calculate it only once.

Comment: did you get an error with the above?

Comment: `@rowcount` isn't a valid PL/SQL identifier.  This looks like a piece of T-SQL code that would run on SQL Server.  You've tagged this question `Oracle`, though.  Are you trying to convert a piece of T-SQL code to PL/SQL?

Comment: You can't mix procedural code (PL/SQL) and regular SQL like that.

Comment: @JustinCave: I don't to convert anything. I just want to number of rows in the table of later use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle you can't mix procedural code and regular SQL like that.

But if you use this:

```
select a / (select count(*) from mytable), 
       b / (select count(*) from mytable)
from myothertable;
```

Oracle will evaluate the `count(*)` only once. There is no need to store the value somewhere to improve performance.

If you want, you could move this into a common table expression:

```
with row_count as (
   select count(*) as numrows
   from mytable
)
select a / (select numrows from row_count), 
       b / (select numrows from row_count)
from myothertable;
```